# How to redefine a Ruby constant without warning?

Tags: ruby, constants, redefine, redefinition

I'm running some Ruby code which evals a Ruby file every time its date changes. In the file, I have constant definitions, like

```
Tau = 2 * Pi
```

and, of course, they make the interpreter display the unwanted "already initialized constant" warning every time, so, I'd like to have the following functions:

```
def_if_not_defined(:Tau, 2 * Pi)
redef_without_warning(:Tau, 2 * Pi)
```

I could avoid the warning by writing all my constant definitions like this:

```
Tau = 2 * Pi unless defined?(Tau)
```

but it is inelegant and a bit wet (not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY)).

Is there a better way to `def_if_not_defined`? And how to `redef_without_warning`?

--

Solution thanks to Steve:

```
class Object
  def def_if_not_defined(const, value)
    mod = self.is_a?(Module) ? self : self.class
    mod.const_set(const, value) unless mod.const_defined?(const)
  end

  def redef_without_warning(const, value)
    mod = self.is_a?(Module) ? self : self.class
    mod.send(:remove_const, const) if mod.const_defined?(const)
    mod.const_set(const, value)
  end
end

A = 1
redef_without_warning :A, 2
fail 'unit test' unless A == 2
module M
  B = 10
  redef_without_warning :B, 20
end
fail 'unit test' unless M::B == 20
```

--

This question is old. The above code is only necessary for Ruby 1.8. In Ruby 1.9, P3t3rU5's answer produces no warning and is simply better.

Comment: Why do you want to redefine a constant? Better to namespace constants by keeping them in your own classes or modules--this way they'll never conflict with other constants.

Comment: I want to redefine a constant because I want to use constants naturally as if I wasn't using an automatic source code reloader, so I won't accept any "just don't use a constant" answer.

Comment: What's inelegant and not DRY about `Tau = 2 * Pi unless defined?(Tau)`?

Comment: 'Tau' is written twice. Not a big deal, except when the name is long or gets renamed uncarefully. But I prefer 'redef :Tau, 2*Pi'

Comment: I'm currently writing the second edition of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and I found this thread while Googling around to solve a Ruby problem I encountered in the process. It didn't turn out to address the exact issue I was having, but let me say that, since I am also the author of The Tau Manifesto, it made me very happy nonetheless. :-)

Comment: @Jordan Simple use case: a library defined a timeout as a constant, but the timeout is too small.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The following module may do what you want. If not it may provide some pointers to your solution

```
module RemovableConstants

  def def_if_not_defined(const, value)
    self.class.const_set(const, value) unless self.class.const_defined?(const)
  end

  def redef_without_warning(const, value)
    self.class.send(:remove_const, const) if self.class.const_defined?(const)
    self.class.const_set(const, value)
  end
end
```

And as an example of using it

```
class A
  include RemovableConstants

  def initialize
    def_if_not_defined("Foo", "ABC")
    def_if_not_defined("Bar", "DEF")
  end

  def show_constants
    puts "Foo is #{Foo}"
    puts "Bar is #{Bar}"
  end

  def reload
    redef_without_warning("Foo", "GHI")
    redef_without_warning("Bar", "JKL")
  end

end

a = A.new
a.show_constants
a.reload
a.show_constants
```

Gives the following output

```
Foo is ABC
Bar is DEF
Foo is GHI
Bar is JKL
```

Forgive me if i've broken any ruby taboos here as I am still getting my head around some of the Module:Class:Eigenclass structure within Ruby

Comment: Sure, the key to this answer is simply first calling `Object.send(:remove_const,'Tau') if Object.const_defined?('Tau')`, which undefines the constant, thus preempting the warning.  Great approach.

Comment: Yep, or just `send(:remove_const, :CONST) if const_defined?(:CONST)` if you're in class (not instance) scope.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach, using $VERBOSE, to suppress warnings, is discussed here:  http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/04/02/suppress_warnings_from_ruby/

Update 2020/5/6:  In response to the comment that the link is now dead, I am pasting an example here from my old project, though I can't say whether and in what circumstances it is a good approach:

```
original_verbose = $VERBOSE
$VERBOSE = nil # suppress warnings
# do stuff that raises warnings you don't care about
$VERBOSE = original_verbose
```

Comment: Yes. As mentioned in your link, a better implementation of silence_warnings exist in Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#M002564  But that approach is inferior to the accepted answer, because it probably has side effects on other threads.

Comment: Also, that link is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redefine a value then don't use constants, use a global variable instead ($tau = 2 * Pi), but that's not a good practice too. You should make it an instance variable of a suitable class.

For the other case, `Tau = 2 * Pi unless defined?(Tau)` is perfectly alright and the most readable, therefore the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the values of the constants are pretty weird (i.e. you have constants set to `nil` or `false`), the best choice would be to use the conditional assignment operator: `Tau ||= 2*Pi`

This will set Tau to 2π if it is `nil`, `false` or undefined, and leave it alone otherwise.

Comment: Nice idea... Unfortunately, it's not very portable: depending on the ruby version and implementation (ruby/jruby), the affectation to a constant with ||= gave me three different results. Either it works quietly as intended (jruby1.5), either I get an "uninitialized constant" failure (ruby1.8), either I get a warning even if no affectation takes place (jruby1.2).