# how to get rid of ruby's warning: already initialized constant

Tags: ruby, xml-rpc

I'm trying to redefine a gem's constant dynamically so I don't need to modify the gem itself.

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'

XMLRPC::Config.const_set("ENABLE_NIL_PARSER", true)

warning: already initialized constant ENABLE_NIL_PARSER
```

Is it possible to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it? Or, rather, is suppressing it sufficient or do you actually wish to not have it occur?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375360/how-to-redefine-a-ruby-constant-without-warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375360/how-to-redefine-a-ruby-constant-without-warning)

Comment: I saw the post mentioned by Josh already but it didn't work in my case.  It complained about `const_defined?': false is not a symbol (TypeError)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way:

```
v, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil
# code goes here
$VERBOSE = v
```

Comment: Okay, turning off the global temporarily fixed it, but I'm curious as to why the previous mentioned solution didn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You may even wrap it in a block, like this

```rb
def ignoring_warnings(&block)
  begin
    v, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil
    block.call if block
  ensure
    $VERBOSE = v
  end
end
```